# boostrap 4 numbers in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Any suggestions on how to add the number of entries a topic has under that topic in a bootstrap navbar like what is shown below?

```
 PHP    Javascript ASP.NET  HTML/CSS
2,456       500     4,444    23,454
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Just write the proper markup...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add the number along with navbar tag you can use below :

```
navbar.component.html

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="javascript">javascript<span class="some class to beautify">{{ javascriptCount}}</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And inside navbar.component.ts you calculate the value of javascriptCount varibale using your business logic

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap 4, why not make use of the `.navbar-text` class?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#text

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="navbar-text text-center"><span class="font-weight-bold d-block">PHP</span>2,456</span>
  <span class="navbar-text text-center"><span class="font-weight-bold d-block">Javascript</span>500</span>
  <span class="navbar-text text-center"><span class="font-weight-bold d-block">ASP.NET</span>4,444</span>
  <span class="navbar-text text-center"><span class="font-weight-bold d-block">HTML/CSS</span>23,454</span>
</nav>
```

If you have other elements built into your Navbar (logo, menu, etc) you'll have to make some adjustments to ensure everything fits, but otherwise `.navbar-text` defaults to sharing the available space equally.

Some additional utility classes to adjust font weights and line breaks offer you additional styling and reduce unnecessary HTML (like line breaks).  And as with any Navbar Component, if you don't want the content to take up 100% of the viewport you can wrap said content in the `.container` class.